# Find the global maximum and minimum values

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, lagrange-multiplier

Find the global maximum and minimum values of the function $f(x,y) = e^{−xy}$ subject to the constraint $x^2 + 4y^2 \le 1$.

Comment: Hi and welcome to the site! Since this is a site that encourages and helps with learning, it is best if you show your own ideas and efforts in solving the question. Can you edit your question to add your thoughts and ideas about it?

Comment: Also, don't get discouraged by the downvote. I downvoted the question and voted to close it because at the moment, it is not up to site standards (you have shown no work you did on your own). If you edit your question so that you show what you tried and how far you got, I will not only remove the downvote, I will add the upvote.

Answer (score 2):

To find an interior critical point, we would need to find a point so that
$$
\frac{\partial}{\partial x}e^{-xy}=-ye^{-xy}=0\qquad\text{and}\qquad\frac{\partial}{\partial y}e^{-xy}=-xe^{-xy}=0
$$
That is, $(x,y)=(0,0)$ is the only interior critical point.

---

To find a critical point on the boundary $x^2+4y^2=1$, we would need to find when, for any $\delta x$ and $\delta y$
$$
x\,\delta x+4y\,\delta y=0
$$
implies that
$$
-ye^{-xy}\,\delta x-xe^{-xy}\,\delta y=0
$$
This would mean that there is a $\lambda$ so that
$$
\left(-ye^{-xy},-xe^{-xy}\right)=\lambda(x,4y)
$$
That is,
$$
4y^2=x^2
$$
Combined with $x^2+4y^2=1$, we get the critical points to be
$$
(x,y)=\left(\pm\frac1{\sqrt2},\pm\frac1{2\sqrt2}\right)
$$
Checking out each of these $5$ critical points shows that the global minimum value of $e^{-1/4}$ occurs at $(x,y)=\left(\frac1{\sqrt2},\frac1{2\sqrt2}\right)$ and $(x,y)=\left(-\frac1{\sqrt2},-\frac1{2\sqrt2}\right)$.